# Fastest way to swap large datasets in textarea

Tags: javascript

I have potentially dozens of sets of logs coming into my UI. To conserve resources, they come one at a time, and after the initial log, we receive partial updates only, which get appended to the pre-existing data. They reach a limit of 9000 lines or so, and we expect up to 20 in memory at a time.

Each log is displayed by selecting a tab. The UI is in Bootstrap, and although we are using the `tab-nav` component, we are NOT switching the content area. We just keep re-using a single textarea.

I tried:

1. Just assigning `value` on the textarea while it was in DOM
2. Detaching from DOM before updating value (see code below:)
3. Similar to above, but with the update logic as a function that was wrapped in the old "setTimeout" trick to force asynchronous behaviour.

Sample code from #2 attempt:

```
$('#myTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var myId = e.target.dataset.tabid; // the "e" is a show.bs.tab event
  var textArea = document.getElementById('logs');
  var par = textArea.parentElement;
  par.removeChild(textArea);
  textArea.value = window.storedData[myId]; // storage for prototyping
  par.appendChild(textArea);
})
```

At the end of the day, they all performed pretty similarly, leading me to surmise that reflow isn't the problem, and that the "asynchronous" trick wasn't netting me any benefit because the DOM update itself still has to execute in its thread in due time.

Is there a better way for doing an efficient "swap" of large-ish amounts of data? My overall goal is to not block the UI while the swap is happening.

[update:] Despite the title, I'm not absolutely married to it being a textarea. But it's ideal because users can CTRL-A and do other plain-text-selection stuff that is sometimes goofed up when using unordered lists or tables.

Comment: Use something like https://clusterize.js.org/

Comment: Unfortunately assigning a string to the value of a `<textarea>` will have to block the UI at some point. 9000 lines doesn't seem like a lot though, are you using some sort of special font or is it just a standard system font?

Comment: Very interesting, Gabriele, I didn't know about that one. Patrick: 9000 isn't a lot, you're right. 9000 x 20 is where it starts to be slow. And it's not necessarily even the adding stage; if I make a page with 20 textareas, and paste 9000 lines into each, no JS, no anything weird, the page becomes noticeably less responsive overall. :( Also: no weird fonts.

Comment: I also wonder how much of it is the 9000 lines being technically one long string (divided by line feeds) set as a value. I wonder what the practical limitations are of textareas in general.

Comment: Interesting... it's already considered "asynchronous" at some level. I was going to settle for putting a "wait" cursor during the operation, but it doesn't happen because the adding of the text is already outside the execution loop. In other words, it flips to "wait", considers the add to be "executed", and then moves to "default" all within nanoseconds so that you don't even see the wait cursor. I don't think there's a way to improve the add portion as-is. Would need totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective thing I did at a colleague's suggestion was disable the browser's built-in productivity tools:

```
<textarea 
  autocomplete="off" 
  autocorrect="off"
  autocapitalize="off" 
  spellcheck="false"
  rows="15"
  class="form-control" 
  id="logs">
</textarea>
```

I don't imagine using the "rows" attribute (rather than an CSS height) mattered, but you never know. It's mostly disabling the auto stuff and the spellcheck. Reduced the insertion time by roughly a third, which brought it into acceptable responsiveness for now. If future needs are different, will investigate clusterize.js.org per Gabriele's suggestion.